# 403 error for js files in vendor directory on Heroku

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cakephp, heroku

My CakePHP v3.x app runs fine in my local Vagrant environment, but when I deploy to Heroku, I get 403 errors for all javascript files located in `/webroot/vendor/...`

CSS and javascript files outside that directory load fine.

```
https://example.com/js/i_load_fine.js
https://example.com/vendor/i_cause_403_error.js
```

/Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684192/heroku-403-forbidden-for-static-js-files) sounds similar, but I checked and .htaccess already has the recommended RewriteCond:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to specify the document root as a second parameter in the Procfile: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 webroot/`

Answer (score 9):

> I wonder if "vendor" is a reserved word in Heroku?

yes, if you will be use "vendor" folder name, may be error 403 errors.
Because root dir web server `vendor/bin/` .
Don't use public name "vendor" and "bin".

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I just saw the same issue (had a "vendor" folder that kept getting 403 errors).

I renamed the vendor folder to "v" (and fixed references) and everything worked just fine.

I wonder if "vendor" is a reserved word in Heroku?